GCC 14 "possibly dangling reference to a temporary" warning or not, depending on the function argument
In the following C++ code GCC 14 with -Wall -Wextra flags produces a possibly dangling reference warning for function g(), but not f(). Why?
/* getval.h */
#include <string>
std::string const & getVal(std::string const & key);

/* main.cpp */
#include "getval.h"
#include <iostream>

void f()
{
  std::string key{"x"};
  std::string const &s = getVal(key);
  std::cout << "x->" << s << '\n';
}

void g()
{
  std::string const &s = getVal("x");
  std::cout << "x->" << s << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  f();
  g();
}

/* getval.cpp */
#include "getval.h"
#include <map>

std::string const & getVal(std::string const & key)
{
  static std::map<std::string, std::string> map = [](){
     std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
     m.emplace("x", "123");
     m.emplace("y", "456");
     return m;
  }();
  static std::string empty;

  auto it = map.find(key);
  return it != map.end() ? it->second : empty; 
}

/*
Output:
/app/main.cpp: In function 'void g()':
/app/main.cpp:13:22: warning: possibly dangling reference to a temporary [-Wdangling-reference]
   13 |   std::string const &s = getVal("x");
      |                      ^
/app/main.cpp:13:32: note: the temporary was destroyed at the end of the full expression 'getVal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"x"), std::allocator<char>()))'
   13 |   std::string const &s = getVal("x");
      |                          ~~~~~~^~~~~
Program returned: 0
x->123
x->123

I would expect it to produce the warning in both cases or none (earlier gcc versions or clang do not produce a warning).

OT: If your compiler and build requirements/limitations support C++17, this is a good use-case for std::optional. Or if you want to use C++23 then perhaps std::expected.

When compiling main.cpp, the compiler does not see the implementation of getVal and may think "what if the implementation is something like return key;?".

Why g but not f? The temporary in question is constructed when satisfying the std::string const & key argument of getVal with "x" (which is a const char *).

This is known gcc issue.
And false positive.
You can

Disable warning with -Wno-dangling-reference or drop -Wextra.
or modernize your code with use of std::string_view (this is just like a fancy version of strings const reference):

[[nodiscard]] std::string_view getVal(std::string_view key)
{
  using namespace std::literals;
  static const std::map<std::string_view, std::string_view> map {
     { "x"sv, "123"sv },
     { "y"sv, "456"sv },
  };
  auto it = map.find(key);
  return it != map.end() ? it->second : ""sv; 
}

https://godbolt.org/z/P4nxh8nYa
Edit:
Since you prefer use #pragma GCC diagnostic and you did it incorrectly, here is better way to do it:
// check if problematic warning -Wdangling-reference is available
#if __GNUC__ >= 13
#define GCC_PUSH_DIAGNOSTIC_DISABLE_DANGLING_REF _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wdangling-reference\"")

#define GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_POP _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
#else
#define GCC_PUSH_DIAGNOSTIC_DISABLE_DANGLING_REF 
#define GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_POP 
#endif

[[nodiscard]] std::string const& getVal(std::string const& key);

void f()
{
    std::string key { "x" };
    std::string const& s = getVal(key);
    std::cout << "x->" << s << '\n';
}

void g()
{
    GCC_PUSH_DIAGNOSTIC_DISABLE_DANGLING_REF
    std::string const& s = getVal("x");
    GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_POP

    std::cout << "x->" << s << '\n';
}

Live demo

Modernizing is not in the cards at this time. I don't think disabling the warnings on the command line would be appropriate, as this needs to be decided on the case-by-case basis.

I posted my own solution as an alternative answer

I'm posting this as a self-answer, thanks to Marek R's comment and the references therein. GCC seems to try to guess what the implementation of the function might be, and it probably considers something like return key; as a likely one. As only the implementer of the function really knows what is happening, I think a reasonable way to deal with this is to use compiler #pragma around the function declaration:
/* getval.h */
#include <string>

#if defined(__GNUC__)
# pragma GCC diagnostic push
# pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdangling-reference" 
#endif

std::string const & getVal(std::string const & key);

#if defined(__GNUC__)
# pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif


did you test this that this doesn't have to be done in place of use not in place of declaration? Anyway I was thinking about this before posting my answer and this is to clunky IMO.

I was correct. You are doing that wrong. See update in my answer.

I modified your example to do it at the place of declaration and it worked. I believe that's a better place to do it, as it's a sort-of guarantee on the function implementation part, not on the usage.
